# How to Monitor Resource Utilization?

Tags: windows, monitoring, cpu-usage, health-monitoring

Is there a tool which logs the system resource utilization like cpu,memory,io and network for a period of time and generate graph ? 
I need to monitor system and identify in which period resource is been highly utilized.
If anyone of you had experience with this kind of tool,kindly suggest.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides third party tools, there is Windows Performance Monitor that can help. It shows  real-time graphs, and can save the performance information into files that you can open and analyze later

[image]

It provides multiple metrics for CPU, memory, I/O and Network utilization, and shows an instance for each processor on the machine. It can also be used to monitor remote machines

[image]

[image]

You can also create collector sets, to have all monitored counters in a single component

[Performance Monitoring Getting Started Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744567%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

[Create a Data Collector Set to Monitor Performance Counters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722414.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think this tool will help you

[System-Resources-Monitoring](http://softwaresolution.informer.com/System-Resources-Monitoring/)

[System Monitoring](http://www.manageengine.com/free-windows-health-monitor/free-windows-health-monitor-index.html)